# How to pull data from another server

Tags: php, mysql, server

so i need to make a clasic beting website.
My client has a betting program that pulls data from his server.
Now i never pulled data from diferent server so i have no idea how to do that ?
Basicly what i want to ask is,how do i get the same data as the program ?
I doubt he will give me acces to his database,so im wondering whats the best way to pull the data.
I was reading around a bit and looks like socketing is used to connect server,but i donno what else do i need.
Any info is appreciated!!
Tnx for your time!

Comment: "pull data"...  that's kind of a broad statement, no? What kind of data? How is the data presented? Are you talking about a scraper that parses the website and gets the data it wants? Is there an API?

Comment: Its a database that gets updated every minute.Bet odds (numbers),jackpots,names etc...You know info that every sport beting website presents you.TAke for example "Livescore.com" see how data is presented there.His program pulls the same type of data with bunch of additional funcions that are not needed on the website.But i dont know how the program does it.What do i need to know from his server to be able to get the needed data he has stored ?

Comment: **What have you tried?** is the first question to answer here.

Comment: I havent tryed bcouse i still didnt accept.Im not a senior,im a junior programmer.I built websites simular to this but i was always the one makeing those databases.Iv never worked on something like this when the data i need is not on the same place as the website.

Comment: Iv seen some articles here about server linking and thats the first thing i was going to try,but first i wanned to see other peoples opinions on this subject.

Comment: Step 1: check whether the server allows automated data retrieval - "Terms of Usage" or some such. (1b: have an idea about the legislation regarding this in every country involved.) - Give consideration to _not_ putting too much load on that server. It is unlikely that there is a database interface open to the world at large: talk to your client who seems to own/operate that server.